# Vertx: CorruptedWebSocketFrameException: received a frame that is not masked as expected

Tags: vert.x

I receive the exceptions:

```
10:20:36.219 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] ERROR io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.impl.EventBusBridgeImpl - SockJSSocket exception
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.CorruptedWebSocketFrameException: received a frame that is not masked as expected
```

Server Code is:

```
public class Strange extends AbstractVerticle {


    private HttpServer server;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        server = this.getVertx().createHttpServer();
        final Router router = Router.router(this.getVertx());
        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
        router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());
        // SOCKS
        final SockJSBridgeOptions opts = new SockJSBridgeOptions()
                .addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex(".*"))
                .addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex(".*"));
        final SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(this.getVertx());
        final var socks = sockJSHandler.bridge(opts, event -> {
            if (event.type() == BridgeEventType.SOCKET_CREATED) {
                log.atInfo().log("Socket was created ...");
            }
            event.complete(true);
        });

        router.route("/*")
                .handler(StaticHandler.create(StaticHandler.DEFAULT_WEB_ROOT))
                .subRouter(socks);
        server.requestHandler(router);
        server.listen(80);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        this.server.close();
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <script src="lib/vertx/sockjs.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="lib/vertx/vertx-eventbus.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>


<script type="module">
    const eventBus = new EventBus('http://localhost:80');
    eventBus.enableReconnect(true);
    eventBus.send("ping", {ping: 42}, {token:"MyToken"}, (error, response) => {
        console.log("pong");
    });
</script>
<h1>Strange test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I used the vert.x version 4.4.2

So it seems like the client cannot send any events to the server, it doesn't matter which format or payload.
Can someone help me to understand why the exceptions will be received and how can I fix it?